# Custom component issue in Angularjs2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I am trying to learn Angularjs2 and make my first app but its not working fine and also not showing any error. I have made "my-app" component with some html "**Angular 2 First App Here is my component**", this one is working fine but when I have made new component named "my-component" with text "Hi, I am {{name}}" its not showing in the browser.

Also when I am trying to remove text form "my-app" like:

Text is: "Angular 2" so it shows my previous text which is "Angular 2 First App"

Please check what I am doing wrong in the below code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/angular2_project/">
    <title>Angular 2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>

<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyComponentComponent} from './my-component.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular 2 First App</h1>
        <h2>Here is my component</h2>
        <my-component></my-component>
    `,
    directives: [MyComponentComponent],
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

my-component.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        Hi, I am {{name}}
    `,
})

export class MyComponentComponent {
    name = 'Ovais';
}
```

Comment: It is working fine when I restart the system but why this is not change instantly?

Comment: Dont learn this. this is the old way to do it. learn new version of Angular2. its changed.

Comment: @micronyks, can you please suggest me any tutorial or article which may help to learn Angularjs2?

Comment: https://angular.io/

Comment: Try to use angular cli, it is fast and will save you all the need to include scripts in your index file.